# Why are Op Stats all 0's and yet Usage Stats show 29 seeks

Tags: sql-server-2012, index-tuning, sp-blitzindex

Why are Op Stats all 0's and yet Usage Stats show 29 seeks.  This was returned from Brent Ozar's sp_blitzindex.

```
Usage Stats                         Op Stats
Reads: 29 (29 seek) Writes:14    0 singleton lookups; 0 scans/seeks; 0 deletes; 0 updates;
```

Comment: Have you tried finding the answer by looking into the source code to see how the SP retrieves both groups of stats?

Answer (score 8):

Usage statistics come from [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx), which tracks the number of execution plans that include an operator touching that index. It's reset on SQL Server service restart, or when the index is modified.

Operational statistics come from [sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174281.aspx), which track the number of times the index has actually been touched. It's reset on a different schedule - when that object's metadata disappears from cache.

Comment: Thanks Brent.  I also found this more detailed explanation:   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174281.aspx#Anchor_4