# sp_blitzIndex Usage stats vs. Op Stats

Tags: sp-blitzindex

The 'Op stats' are the numbers that give us the best information about index usage but can be reset at any time.
If I look to the number of writes on the Clustered index (20.716), and I have approximately the same database usage every day, Is it then safe to conclude that numbers in the 'Op stats' haven't been reset for about 6 days?

My argumentation for this is:[image]

```
Writes on the clustered index happen on insert, updates and deletes. (20.716)
My server has been up for 16.67 days.
I have 7590 updates in the 'Op stats' (insert, updates, deletes)
16.67/20716*7590 = 6.1
```

So, my conclusion is, the 'Op stats' haven't been reset for the last 6 days.
Would you tend to agree with me on this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-operational-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

> The data returned by sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats exists only as
> long as the metadata cache object that represents the heap or index is
> available. This data is neither persistent nor transactionally
> consistent. This means you cannot use these counters to determine
> whether an index has been used or not, or when the index was last
> used. For information about this, see sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
> (Transact-SQL).
>
> The values for each column are set to zero whenever the metadata for
> the heap or index is brought into the metadata cache and statistics
> are accumulated until the cache object is removed from the metadata
> cache. Therefore, an active heap or index will likely always have its
> metadata in the cache, and the cumulative counts may reflect activity
> since the instance of SQL Server was last started. The metadata for a
> less active heap or index will move in and out of the cache as it is
> used. As a result, it may or may not have values available. Dropping
> an index will cause the corresponding statistics to be removed from
> memory and no longer be reported by the function. Other DDL operations
> against the index may cause the value of the statistics to be reset to
> zero.

The comparison of both columns are different. See also Brent's explaination where both come from:

> Usage statistics come from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats, which tracks
> the number of execution plans that include an operator touching that
> index. It's reset on SQL Server service restart, or when the index is
> modified.
>
> Operational statistics come from sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats,
> which track the number of times the index has actually been touched.
> It's reset on a different schedule - when that object's metadata
> disappears from cache.

[Why are Op Stats all 0's and yet Usage Stats show 29 seeks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139561/why-are-op-stats-all-0s-and-yet-usage-stats-show-29-seeks)

So I think your assumption is right.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :-)